# How to get global coordinates inside DragTarget.onMove (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, dragtarget

I need to get position of draggable inside `DragTarget.onMove`. But in `DragTargetDetails.offset` we have some weird values.
In source code I see that it is set to `avatar._lastOffset` which is `globalPosition - dragStartPoint`. But I don't have access to any of those to be able to calculate global position or local position inside DragTarget.
Documentation sais that `DragTargetDetails.offset` is 'The global position when the specific pointer event occurred on the draggable.' but in reality it is a global position minus start drugging point which seems to be useless, how I can use that value?

I prepared a simple example, where you can see offsets from `Draggable.onDragUpdate` (which is real global position) and from `DragTarget.onMove`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Offset _dragUpdateOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _moveOffset = Offset.zero;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Draggable(
          data: "Test Data",
          child: const Text("Drag me"),
          feedback: const Material(child:Text("Draggable")),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          onDragUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              _dragUpdateOffset = details.globalPosition;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
            Text("dragUpdate: ${_dragUpdateOffset.dx},${_dragUpdateOffset.dy}"),
            const Text("vs"),
            Text("onMove: ${_moveOffset.dx},${_moveOffset.dy}")
          ],),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: DragTarget(
                onMove: (details) {
                  _moveOffset = details.offset;
                },
                onWillAccept: (data) => true,
                builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) => SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text("DragTarget"),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping Draggable with Listener and use "onPointerMove: (details)".

Comment: There is no problem with `Draggable`, it has `onDragUpdate` which does the job. But in my real project `Draggable` and `DragTarget` are on different branches of Widget tree, so I need a way to do that with `DragTarget` and `onMove` should do exactly what I want, but it returns weird coordinates in `details`.

Comment: Sure I can wrap `DragTarget` with `Listener` and I can imagine others workarounds, but my question is not about workarounds, my question is about `DragTarget.onMove` and how to properly use it. Or maybe it is just implemented wrongly??

Comment: I have had issues with Draggble coordinates, so i don't trust it, and use workarounds :)